# text in footer won't align to bottom center

Tags: html, css

As the title suggests I'm trying to align my text in my footer to be horizontally center and aligned to the bottom.

Having read other's solutions, I've tried to set the parent div to relative, the p element to absolute, and then bottom: 0;/vertical-align: bottom; But doesn't work.

What happens is that the text moves up into the above div and is no longer horizontally centered.

```css
/*Section3*/
#section3 {
  height: 50%;
  background: #6ed3cf;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 0.5em;
  height: 20em;
}

#section3 h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 200;
}

#section3 i {
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: black;
}

/*Footer*/
#footer {
  background:#fff;
  color: black;
  height: 10%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
}

#footer p {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="section3" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
 <div>
  <h2>header</h2> 
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
     <p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i   ></a>  
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<div id="footer">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <p>text</p> 
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you are using `display: table` on footer? Either remove this property or use `width: 100%` also. And remove unnecessary `position: absolute` from `p`.

Comment: When you apply `display: table` on an element, its width then depends on the content inside unless explicitly applied either by `width` attribute or via css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about certain properties on your components, but here's what I would do:

Remove `position: absolute` on your `<p>` element, and remove the `display: table` from your `<footer>`.

Like so:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

/*Section3*/

#section3 {
  height: 50%;
  background: #6ed3cf;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 0.5em;
  height: 20em;
}

#section3 h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 200;
}

#section3 i {
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: black;
}


/*Footer*/

#footer {
  background: #fff;
  color: black;
  height: 10%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

#footer div {
  height: 100%;
}

#footer .row > div {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

#footer p {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="section3" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
  <div>
    <h2>header</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i   ></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Footer -->
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This definitely centers the text horizontally, but it is still not aligned to bottom

Comment: @suonpera, the "text" is at the bottom. You want it inside the teal background or?

Comment: yes it is inside the footer, but it is not aligned to the bottom. If I increase the height of the footer, the text will be positioned at the top of the div

Comment: @suonpera, oh I see. Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6tokejmy/2/)? Let me know, and I'll update the answer above.

Comment: No. If you increase the height of the footer you will see that the text is positioned at the top of the div (footer), not the bottom

Comment: @suonpera, gotcha. You want to align the text within the footer to the bottom. Not the footer itself. Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6tokejmy/4/)

Comment: That works! Should I then use bottom:; to adjust the text from the bottom? E.g. if I want it 1em from the bottom?

Comment: @suonpera, yes. I'll update my answer to reflect the code on the fiddle. Please consider marking it as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: Just copied your code into my own. It doesn't work.. Now the footer has jumped almost to the top of the website

Comment: @suonpera, Yeah I it gets complicated when the footer doesnt fit the window. Try the code above again - I've edited it.

Comment: Still doesn't work. then the text is not horizontally aligned

Comment: @suonpera, it is for me. It's dead in the center horizontally, and at the bottom vertically.

Comment: That's weird. On my end it's positioned all the way to the left. What would your solution be if I don't use columns? If it's just the footer div with the text inside.

Comment: @suonpera, you're running the snippet of my answer right? I'll update the fiddle too then: https://jsfiddle.net/6tokejmy/5/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130783/discussion-between-chris-and-suonpera).

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when i gave width:100%; to my footer property. if you do that then the text aligns itself to middle. PS, my reputation doesnt allow me to add a comment...

Comment: Is does position the text to the middle, horizontally, but it is still not aligned to the bottom of the footer div

Comment: you should check if "row" and "container" class are not interfering with your footer property since they're nested inside your footer

Answer (score 0):

Please add width style for P element of #footer as following :

```
 #footer p {
    font-size: 0.7em;
     text-align: center;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     vertical-align: bottom;
     width:100%; /* added new style */
 }
```

If you have any issue please let me know.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You just try this.

```
#footer {
  background:#fff;
  color: black;
  height: 10%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

See if this solve your purpose

```css
#section3 {
 height: 50%;
 background: #6ed3cf;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 0 0.5em;
 height: 20em;
}

#section3 h2 {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: 200;
}

#section3 i {
 padding: 0.5em;
 color: black;
}

/*Footer*/
#footer {
    /* background: #fff; */
    /* color: black; */
    /* height: 10%; */
    /* font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; */
    /* position: relative; */
    /* display: table; */
    background: #6ed3cf;
}

#footer p {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    text-align: center;
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* bottom: 0; */
    /* vertical-align: bottom; */
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="section3" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
  <div>
   <h2>header</h2> 
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i   ></a>  
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>


</div>
<!-- Footer -->
 <div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
     <p>text</p> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```